# Creating a Datawarehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Currently our team is having a major database management/data management issue where hundreds of databases are being built and used for minor/one off applications where the app should really be pulling from an already existing database.

Since our security is so tight, the owners of these Systems of authority will not allow others to pull data from them at a consistent (App Necessary) rate, rather they allow a single app to do a weekly pull and that data is then given to the org.

I am being asked to compile all of those publicly available (weekly snapshots) into a single data warehouse for end users to go to. We realistically are talking 30-40 databases each with hundreds of thousands of records.

What is the best way to turn this into a data warehouse? Create a SQL server and treat each one as its own DB on the server? As far as the individual app connections I am less worried, I really want to know what is the best practice to house all of the data for consumption.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is more of a simple data lake. If all you're being asked for is a single place for the existing data to live as-is, then sure, directly pulling all 30-40 databases to a new server will get that done. One thing to note is that if they're creating [Database Snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), those wouldn't be helpful here. With actual database backups, it would be easy to build a process that would copy and restore those to your new server. This is assuming all of the sources are on SQL Server.

"Data warehouse" implies a certain level of organization beyond that, to facilitate reporting on an aggregate of the data across the multiple sources. Generally you'd identify any concepts that are shared between the databases and create a unified table for each concept, then create an ETL (extract, transform, load) process to standardize the data from each source and move it into those unified tables. This would be a large lift for one person to build. There's plenty of resources that you could read to get you started--Ralph Kimball's The Data Warehouse Toolkit is a comprehensive guide.

In either case, a tool you might want to look into is [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver15). It's good for copying data across servers and has drivers for multiple different RDBMS platforms. You can schedule SSIS packages from SQL Agent. It has other features that could help for data warehousing as well.